# How to get the roots of

Tags: polynomials

$d^4 -1.066d^3 - 0.28d^2 - 2.39d - 0.63= 0$

I need to find the values of d which satisfy this equation because I found it hard containing a degree of $4$.

Comment: take your calculator or ask me

Comment: [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) is your friend here.

Comment: I could, however, my calculator can make it up for the 3rd degree.

Comment: and i'm also a friend of you

Comment: ok i will try it with my calculator

Comment: "my calculator can make it up for the 3rd degree." that's a bad excuse in the age of internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation can be factorized into
$$( d-1.93552) ( d+0.261667) \left( d^2+0.607854
   d+1.24392\right)=0$$

$$d_1\approx -0.303927 - 1.0731 i,d_2\approx -0.303927 + 1.0731 i,d_3\approx -0.261667,d_4\approx 1.93552$$

Comment: Why did you leave that cliffhanger by not factorising the quadratic ?

Comment: yea, since the quadratic has only complex solutions

Comment: Understandable ...

Comment: and we get $$d_1\approx -0.303927 - 1.0731 i,d_2\approx -0.303927 + 1.0731 i,d_3\approx -0.261667,d_4\approx 1.93552$$

Comment: i have added ALL solutions

Comment: all big letters are corrected

Comment: thank you for editing my post!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner must admit that without an algebra software it is almost impossible to see the factorization...

Comment: that can be, can you solve the quartic by hand?